# How to remove last divider from the list in Grid system in Material Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the grid system in material Ui. And make a list of statements with a divider. I want to remove the very last divider from the list.
Here is the code snippet of my TSX file

```
return (
    <Grid key={index}>
      <Grid style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Grid item direction="column">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={listItem.className} color={listItem.color} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3} direction="column">
          <span style={{ paddingLeft: '5px', fontSize: '12px', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{listItem.title}:</span>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={9}>
          <span
            className={classes.listSubHeader}
            style={
              listItem.title === 'Spread & Liquidity' && listItem.color === theme.palette.error.main
                ? { color: theme.palette.error.main, fontWeight: 'bold' }
                : { color: theme.palette.text.primary }
            }>
            {listItem.sentence}
          </span>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <hr className={classes.divider} />
    </Grid>
  );
```

I want to remove(border: 'none') the last divider only from the grid system. Your precious suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Something like `<hr className={index == this_array.length - 1 ? classes.alternative_divider : classes.divider} />` should work, but I don't know the name of the array (and therefore just called it this_array) and I made up a name for the alternative divider css class.

Comment: I dont see a border, are  you wanting to remove the final hr element?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you are using MaterialUI, why are you using the `<hr>` tag and not Material's [Divider Component](https://mui.com/components/dividers/) ?

Comment: @A Harworth Yes

Comment: @Jamie_D I don't know how to get the 'dashes' divider in material UI that's why I am using <hr> with CSS instead of the Mui component.

Comment: I added a workaround for you in an answer in case you are curious ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you would rather use @mui's divider component rather than the `hr` tag:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';

const dividerStyle = {
  borderTop: "2px dashed black"
}

export default function DashedDivider() {
  return (
        <Divider sx={dividerStyle}/>
  );
}
```